# Embed function in swiftmailer not working

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I want to send logo of our company in email inline & not as attachment. I have this code for sending out email.

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('hostname', port, 'ssl')
    ->setUsername('email')
    ->setPassword('password');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject')
    ->setFrom(array('example@example.com' => 'example'))
    ->setTo($email)
    ->setBody('
<html>
<body>
  <img src="' . $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('images/maillogo.jpg')) . '" />
  <p align="left"> Greetings, </p>
  <br>
  <p align="left"> Dear ' . $firstname . '
  <p align="left"> Your order ' . $orderid . ' has been placed with us. Kindly expect the delivery before 9pm.</p>
  <br>
  <p align="left"> Thank you for Shopping with us. Have a great day. </p>
</body>
</html>',
    'text/html');

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

However I get this error

`Call to a member function embed() on a non-object.`
Any idea how to resolve this? Looked at so many threads but couldn't get an answer.

I tried this method as well but it send an email with attachment & not logo in the first line.

```
->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('path to image here.jpg')  
->setDisposition('inline'));
```

Any suggestions or something?

Comment: Did you try to var_dump($transport) and $mailer? There is a typo in first line - port is not a variable.

Comment: Oh no, there is no typo, it's 465 instead of port, just for illustration purpose, I put port number over there.

Comment: Without just that single line of attaching image, it works fine, I get emails within a sec but as that line of code has been added, no emails are going.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable `$message` before it has been set to any value.
Try splitting up the "fluid" interface calls, so that `$message` has a value before you call `setBody`